# Having $X \sim \Gamma(3,4)$ find pdf of $Y = X/2$

Tags: probability, statistics

I know, that I can and should start with pdf of $X$. The result I got is two times smaller, than what I would expect. I know from the lecture, that when I do a variable substitution I should multiply by the derivative of the substitution. This even works for me, with this example. I am now just wondering why I should do so.
I remember, that You have to multiply expression with the derivative of substitution while making integral calculations. But here, I don't compute any integral, so I just don't see why I should multiply by the derivative of substitution.
If anybody can explain it to me, I'd be extremely happy. Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is a bit unclear. But from what I can understand, I think you are confusing a **linear change of variable** with a **convolution**. Those two are different.
In a linear change of variable, you are not computing an integral. In this case, 
you want
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{f_X(2y)}{\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|}.$$

If you are asking why you have to divide by $\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|$,
I think [this link](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/157) might help.